# "Unable to display this Web Part." error when changing list column width

Tags: sharepoint-designer

When I edit the width of a column in a list on my sharepoint site using SPD 2010. 
and after I reload the webpage I get the error:

> "Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open
>   this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML
>   editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists,
>   contact your Web server administrator."

I've tried so many different things and read alot of forums but nothing helped me so far.

Does anyone have an idee why this happends and how to fix it? I just need custom widths on my list without the error.

Comment: since it has already been more then 24 hours I bet that this post is somewhere around the 15th page so this is never gonna get answerd is it?

Comment: did you check on ULS which is the error?

Comment: Did u try to create a new view with new column width and show in a web part?

Answer (score 1):

I'm by no means an expert, but I had the same issue as you, and I fixed it by reducing the number of columns in the list view (not in SPD) and working backwards.

The reason it doesn't display is because there is *too* much width and the default setting is for any width overflow to generate an error.

If you absolutely need all of your columns, try this method of operation:
1) Navigate to SPD, go to your custom list view
2) Instead of starting by enlarging one column, start by reducing the size of some others (make judgement calls to decide which ones)
3) Save, preview to see if it still appears. Reduced columns should reflect the changes.
4) Enlarge your column, save, preview. If it doesn't appear, try increasing the width by a smaller proportion.